# How Inheritance works in Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, ui-automation

I am Vikki and I am trying to learn the python .
I have below query , 
I have one base class

```
class Parent: 
     def returnsString(self, str):
          return self.txt
```

similarly , there are few other functions in the parent class , like 
returnInt, returnBool etc .

now I created other class :

```
class Child(Parent):
   def main():
   obj = Child()
   print('Trying Inheriting here : ',obj.returnsString())

AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute returnsString
```

Now , in Java we when extend a class then we have direct access of the base class methods and objects, but as in python if I am trying a similar approach I am not able to do so .

Can someone guide me if we can access all the methods and properties of the base class or In python every time I have to override the function , 
can someone please help me on same.

Comment: The short answer to the question how to call base class method through a derived class instance is: `super(Child, obj).returnsString()`, where `obj` is the instance of the derived `class` and `Child` is the name of the derived class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code.
First, your BaseClass definition is ambigious to me. Where is the self.txt attribute assigned? You don't have your constructor defined, in which you are supposed to intialize all the attributes. Also. you don't really need the `str` argument for `returnsString` method, because all you do is just return the value of `self.txt`.
 Try something like this:

```
class Parent: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.txt = "Base class str."

     def returnsString(self):
          return self.txt
```

If you don't want to overload anything in your derived class, it's definition could look like this:

```
class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

WIth this setup, you can now test your `returnsString` method:

```
def main():
    obj = Child()
    print('Trying Inheriting here : ', obj.returnsString())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output of executing your Python script will be:

> Trying Inheriting here :  Base class str.

Answer (score 1):

The current error in this code is that you self invoked the Child() method. `obj = Child()` Which means you instantiated a copy of itself and not a Parent class object which is not good practice IMO. If you want to access other items from the same object consider explicitly announcing `self.<insert item name>` this adds a level of readability and cleanliness.

Anything else you might need is extremely detailed in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=class#inheritance), the python.org reference is your best bet for answers.

PS. Take not that classes and their methods might change significantly from py2 to py3. I have considered the answer under py3.

PPS. Use the following code and run it again.

```
obj = Parent;
```

PPPS. Always try and write ;'s where line breaks. It's better for starters, and the interpreter might give you clearer error reports.

Comment: Thank you Georgi , will sure mark your advise , thank you very much again :)

Comment: If you'd be so kind to either accept it as an answer or point up I'd appreciate it. Glad I could help.